# Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift, xcode, video

I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm trying to save a video to the documents folder after recording it (so I can then upload to a server) but I'm getting the above error. I understand what the error is saying but I'm not sure how to fix it. I got the code below from another answer on Stack.
What am I missing?

The build fails on this line:

```
videoData?.write(toFile: dataPath, atomically: false)
```

The full function is:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){

    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! NSURL
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL as URL)
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docsDirectory = getDocumentsDirectory()
    let dataPath = docsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/videoFileName.mp4")

    videoData?.write(toFile: dataPath, atomically: false)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Just use data method `write(to: URL)` instead of `write(foFile: String)` or pass the url `path` property. Btw naming a url `dataPath` is misleading. Change it to `fileURL` and pass its path `fileURL.path` but better to use the URL method counterpart when possible  `try videoData?.write(to: fileURL)`

Comment: Well that easy, lol. and I agree, I'll rename that...  thanks a bunch

Comment: Why do you cast to `NSURL` and then *back* to `URL`? And do not call `appendingPathComponent` passing a string with a leading `slash`. The API handles the path separators properly.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to this and I was following someone else example, if there's an easier way to do this I'm happy to be shown it and learn..

Comment: @KeeneScouser The same applies to `NSData`, you should drop the `NS` prefix whenever it is possible. Swift native type is `Data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use data method `write(to: URL)` instead of `write(foFile: String)` or pass the `URL` path property. Btw naming a `URL` dataPath is misleading. Change it to `fileURL` and pass its path `fileURL.path` but better to use the `URL` method counterpart when possible. Also as already mentioned in comments by @vadian there is no need to cast to `NSURL` and back to `URL` and don't pass a leading slash when appending a path component. The same applies to `NSData`, you should drop the `NS` prefix whenever it is possible. Swift native type is `Data`.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
    if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
        do {
            let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoURL)
            let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("videoFileName.mp4")
            try videoData.write(to: fileURL)
            // pass atomic options if you would like to automatically override any existing file if needed
            // try videoData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```